# wait or sleep or something

Tags: java, android

A numerical time value (not shown here) is available to this method in real time, that could conceivably be used to place a temporary hold on the following stop from being carried out:

```
public void stopRec(){
 audioRecord.stop();
  try {
   dos.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Let's say a time forward has commenced and we're now t=0.25 into the ellapsed count.  But user is moving to invoke the above *now*, and I want to prevent that underlying method from transpiring until t>0.5 into the count.

It's fine if the user wants to (and does) press the close button, go ahead, and I'll throw a wait message on screen that will say more or less "Fine, stopping...."  But the thing won't actually stop until >0.5 occurs behind the scenes.

How would a wait statement (I wouldn't imagine a loop would be good because of wasted CPU cycles) be used in the above scenario?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to schedule a delay task of stop using ScheduledExecutorService.